# How to lock swagger ui with login screen to only give access to the API end points to only the Authorised users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger-ui

how do you lock the swagger ui on the asp.net so that only authenticated users gets to see the API end points.

Comment: What's the reasoning for doing this? If the APIs are controlled with authorization then no one can call them unless they have the correct credentials anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger does not support user based visuals, if you want to do this you would have to include something in middleware to look for the /swagger url and check for any authenticated sessions.

Another possible work around can be found here;

[Swashbuckle Hide unreferenced model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116507/swashbuckle-hide-unreferenced-model/46122090#46122090)

Answer (score 0):

I thought too much effort to put a wall in a doc, if it is not for visualization, we just not publish in production environment to our internal apis, based on an environment variable.